# expression must have an integral or unscoped enum type

Tags: c++

```
bool calHit(double angle, double velocity) {
const double g = 9.80665;
double range;
    range = ((velocity ^ 2)*sin(2 * angle)) / g;


}
```

this returns an error saying expression must have an integral or unscoped enum type. the error so far is only on velocity.

I am not casting any data types or rounding. Really don't get why this is happening.

Comment: `velocity ^ 2` doesn't do what you think it does!

Comment: `velocity ^ 2` means `velocity` XOR 2, that operator does not accept floating point parameter (and is of course not what you want).

Comment: Oh look two semi-answers in comments good job

Answer (score 2):

The problem in this code is `velocity ^ 2`: the `^` operator does not do exponentation in C++ (instead, it does a bitwise XOR). Instead, write `velocity * velocity` or [`std::pow(velocity, 2)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow).

The error comes from the fact that XORing a double with an int is not possible, so `velocity XOR 2` is not possible since `velocity` is a double.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem before. since velocity is double type.  velocity ^ 2 might be unscoped. Thus velocity * velocity  can solve the problem.

```
int c;
int d;
int f = (c ^ 2 + d ^ 2);
```